# How to load the layout first in catalog category page?

Tags: category-products

When Product list page gets loaded  layout should be loaded first (ie the grid) leaving space for images.Then the images should be loaded in their respective spaces. What should be done for that. kindly help.

Comment: explain more in details.

Comment: @AshishMadankar I have updated my question. I just want to get the layout loaded first instead of images.

Answer (score 0):

What you are describing is called lazy loading.

Unfortunately it is way too tricky to give you a full explanation on how to do it on the catalog product list page.

I suggest you take a look at this module which implements what you need: https://github.com/mgtcommerce/Mgt_LazyImageLoader

The idea is too use a JavaScript lazy load library and hide the original product image in a data attribute by replacing:

```
 <img src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>"
```

width="135" height="135" alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product,      'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />

By:

```
<img class="lazy" src="getSkinUrl('images/mgt_lazy_image_loader/loader.gif'); ?>" data-src="helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'small_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'small_image'), null, true) ?>" />
```